# jquery question generate input value by other input value

Tags: jquery, database, laravel, forms

I have simple  ticket form which has hidden input with last ticket serial no. BMPS3001 I need that jquery generate newticket value in not hidden input and when they enter quantity for generating tickets script make as many new serial no. as quantity input value for example script generates new serial at the start BMPS3002 but if i change quantity 4 it generates three more in input array [BMPS3002,BMPS3003,BMPS3004,BMPS3005] .
Last question if i post that form can i use for cycle in laravel DB::Begintrasaction? because i need to create entries in db for every ticket no same values for other inputs only serial no. different value. Thanks

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="lastTicketValue" value=BMPS3001>
Generated ticked number
<input type="text" name="generatedticket[]" value="BMPS3002">
Quantity of tickects
<input type="number" value="">
Ticket value
<input type="text" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: If you put 3 inside quatity, you want 3 input or 1 input with 3 values?
And if you want 3 values, they have to be displayed or stored elsewhere?

Comment: I need 3 values and yes then they need to be passed to db. Like 3 db rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code detect the change of the quantity, generate the serial numbers and print them inside the "generatedticket" input.
Note that for example you put 2 inside quantity it will generate "BMPS3002, BMPS3003", and then you put 1, it will generate "BMPS3004". You can avoid this by commenting:

```
var lastEl = list[list.length - 1];
console.log("lastEl " + lastEl);
lastTicket.val(lastEl);
```

For example you can insert this 3 lines of code inside the submit of the form.

**HTML**:

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" id="lastTicketValue" value=BMPS3001>
    <input type="text" id="generatedticket" value="">
    <input id="ticket-quantity" type="number" value="">
    <input type="text" value="">
</form>
```

**JS**:

```
$("form").on("change", "#ticket-quantity", function () {
    var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
    console.log(quantity);
    if (quantity > 0){
        var generatedTicket = $("#generatedticket");
        var lastTicket = $("#lastTicketValue");

        var lastTicketValue = lastTicket.val();
        var lastTicketNumber = (lastTicketValue
            .match(/\d+\.\d+|\d+\b|\d+(?=\w)/g) || [])
            .map(function (v) { return +v; }).pop();

        console.log("lastTicketValue " + lastTicketValue);
        console.log("lastTicketNumber " + lastTicketNumber);

        var list = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < quantity + 1; i++) {
            list.push(lastTicketValue.replace(lastTicketNumber, lastTicketNumber + i));
        }

        console.log(list);
        generatedTicket.attr("value", list);
        var lastEl = list[list.length - 1];
        console.log("lastEl " + lastEl);
        lastTicket.val(lastEl);
    }
});
```

**JS Fiddle**:
https://jsfiddle.net/baj1pgoz/